# Updating list item using foreach Knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js

The knockout website has a great example of adding and removing list items using a foreach binding, but how would you update these values?  I've tried doing so in the following fiddle, but the DOM elements do not respond to my update: http://jsfiddle.net/SC5Lw/1/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.updatePerson">Update</a>
    </li>
</ul>

var person1 = ko.observable({ name: 'Bert' });
var person2 = ko.observable({ name: 'Charles' });
var person3 = ko.observable({ name: 'Denise' });

self.people = ko.observableArray([person1, person2, person3]);

...

self.updatePerson = function(person) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < self.people.length ; i++)
    {
        if(self.people[i].name === person.name)
        {
            self.people[i].name = 'Bob';
        }
    }
};
```

I've made the elements of the observableArray into observables themselves, so I'm not sure why the elements they are bound to don't react to changing the property in the view model.

Comment: Show your HTML with your bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a class for people with a `ko.observable` called `name`. That's not what you've done here. You've made `person1` and observable, but it contains an object literal with a normal property called `name`.

Something like this:

```
function Person(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
}
```

Now in your parent VM:

```
var person1 = new Person('Bert');
var person2 = new Person('Charles');
var person3 = new Person('Denise');

self.people = ko.observableArray([person1, person2, person3]);
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SC5Lw/2/).

Also, I wouldn't bother with your loop to find the matching `person`. You already have the person, so just change it's property right there.

So instead of this (which doesn't work anyway because `people` is a function, not a property):

```
self.updatePerson = function(person) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < self.people.length ; i++)
    {
        if(self.people[i].name === person.name)
        {
            self.people[i].name = 'Bob';
        }
    }
};
```

You can just do:

```
self.updatePerson = function(person) {
    person.name("Bob");
}
```

You could even make this cleaner by moving this function to your `Person` view model and doing it there:

```
function Person(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.updateMe = function() {
        self.name("Bob");
    }
}
```

Which avoids having to bind `$parent` in your `foreach` loop:

```
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: updateMe">Update</a>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SC5Lw/4/) with those updates too.

Comment: Do you have this working in JSFiddle?  I can't seem to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/SC5Lw/3/

Comment: @user3123391: Yes, I added a fiddle. You had a bunch of other problems that needed fixing too. Especially when you are using an `observableArray`, you can't do `myObservableArray.length`, because `myObservableArray` is a function. You need `myObservableArray().length`.

Comment: Working with `ko.observableArray` can sometimes trip you up, because some functions that you'd usually find on a regular array (e.g. `push`, `remove`) work directly, but with some (`length` or even indexing the array) you need to get the underlying array for. So `myObservableArray.push(item)` works just fine, but `myObservableArray[0]` does not. You need `myObservableArray()[0]`. And worse, `myObservableArray().push(item)` won't work because you've by-passed the observable part!!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still getting used to everything observable being a function.  Coming from a C# background that gets a little confusing.

Comment: @user3123391: Yeah, it takes a while to get used to. It's because property `getters` and `setters` aren't supported in older browsers.